# How to remove an e-commerce transaction?

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics

I have implemented google analytics ecommerce tracking in my website. But there was a mistake while passing parameters to google analytics. My order get tracked but product sku code is not set.
Its a dummy order that i dont want show in any google analytics report.
Can you suggest how can i delete this order from google analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid you cannot remove data from GA once it has been collected.

What you can do is:

**hide it**: create an Advanced segment, the transaction remains in your GA profile but at least it is not included in the reports.

**make a copy**: copy the profile and delete the old one (it means you lose historical data)

Comment: Could you please elaborate how can i create Advanced segment? I want to show only those records which SKU code is set.

Comment: Hi @Apeksha, sorry I was out for a while.

Here is how to create a segment:
https://blog.kissmetrics.com/new-google-analytics-advanced-segments/

In order to filter out records where SKU is empty, you can use an advanced segment like: 
Exclude > Sessions > Product SKU > matches regexp > .
The "." (dot) means any character. This will exclude from your reports all the sessions that ended up with a transaction for which the SKU is empty.

Comment: Yes. its work. Instead of checking  regexp i have just set product SKU > exactly matches > (not set) . its works for me.

Comment: but is the filteration applied to the graph also?

Comment: Yes, filter will apply to charts too.

Comment: By the way, good that you didn't use the filter I proposed! 
I messed up and this filter would have filtered out any session with a transaction and a SKU from your data. You would be left with sessions without transactions and sessions with transactions and no SKU. Shall not answer this kind of questions by night, sorry (O_o')

Answer (score 1):

There is one more option:

1.- You could create a new transaction with the same amount in money, but with a negative sign. For example, if you have recored a transaction for 1,000 dollars, you could recreate it with a "-1000.00" amount. Doing this would "cancell" the wrong transaction.

Important: This will only work when the user sees a long period of time, including the wrong transaction and the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Julien is right. You cannot remove the data.

There're a couple more options in addition to Julien's suggestions though

1. You can go to "Filters" option of the view and try to see if you can filter it out. Luckily, ecommerce transactions have their own category that can help you narrow down the variable you need to use. ([screenshot attached](http://s30.postimg.org/3yxdhkyht/image.png))
2. Go a little more advanced than filters and use "Data Import" where you import the ecommerce transactions via a spreadsheet thereby overwriting the transactions for that day. So, what you would essentially do is take all the real transactions of ecommerce from your ecommerce application, export them to CSV and then upload it into GA without the test transaction.

Lastly, a tip: create a test profile for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

One of the answers hinted at data imports (but in a way that would probably not have worked). Universal Analytics actually introduced a way to [refund transactions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6014861?hl=en) (effectively canceling them out) via data imports. However this only works if the data was collected via [enhanced e-commerce](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce?hl=en) tracking. As per documentation:

> In order to process refunds you need to have collected transaction
>   data with the ec.js plugin

With standard e-commcerce-tracking Omar Gonzales' answer is still the only working option (I'd like to add the additonal caveat that the negative transaction might be attributed to the wrong channel, so make sure to look at the source/medium/campaign data for the transaction you want to cancel out and supply that data via utm parameters).